# run in python a program added in .bashrc $PATH

Tags: python, bash, path, subprocess

I want to use an external program I usually use in a bash Terminal into a python function

This program is added  in my .bashrc :

```
PATH=$PATH:/the/dir/containing/my_prog
```

So in my Terminal I can run :

```
my_prog arg1
```

How can I, in python, run (e.g. with `os.system()`  or `subprocess` ) `my_prog` ?

because the `.bashrc` must be read initially by and I can't load it.

`my_prog` uses itself some others progs defined in `.bashrc $PATH`, that's why it  must be loaded ...

Thanks for your help !

Comment: You mean you want a parser which reads in the `.bashrc` within a python script and sets the `PATH` variable correctly?

Answer (score 1):

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["/the/dir/containing/my_prog", arg1])
```

or possibly

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["my_prog", arg1], shell=True)
```

if you're relying on bashrc to set the path to my_prog.  I'm not entirely sure what you're asking :)